# How to use headerClass property of ag-grid in angular?

Tags: angular, ag-grid

Recently I added `a-grid` grid to my angular project.

I want to change font-family of header of my grid. I know that there is a property named as `headerClass` and it is the place of header class definition. but when I applied this property nothing changed to my header font family.

It is html file:

```
<ag-grid-angular  style="width: 100%; height: 500px;"
                  class="ag-theme-blue"
                  [rowData]="gridOptions.rowData"
                  [columnDefs]="gridOptions.columnDefs"
                  [defaultColDef]="gridOptions.defaultColDef"
                  [enableRtl]="agGridPropeties.enableRTL"
                  [localeText]="localeTextPersian"
                  [rowSelection]="agGridPropeties.rowSelection"
                  [multiSortKey]="agGridPropeties.multiSortKey"
                  [pagination]="agGridPropeties.pagination"
                  [paginationPageSize]="agGridPropeties.paginationPageSize"
> 
</ag-grid-angular>
```

It is my class:

```
.my-header-class {
  font-family: tahoma;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

and it is my ts file:

```
public gridOptions: any = {
  defaultColDef: {
    resizable: true,
    sortable: true,
    filter: true,
    headerClass: 'my-header-class'
  },

  columnDefs : [
    {headerName: 'Make', field: 'make'},
    {headerName: 'Model', field: 'model'},
    {headerName: 'Price', field: 'price'},
    {headerName: 'Country', field: 'country'},
  ],

  rowData : [
      { make: 'TOYOTA', model: 'Celica', price: 35000, country:'Japan'},
      { make: 'FORD', model: 'Mondeo', price: 32000, country:'USA'},
      { make: 'BENZ', model: 'C200', price: 100000, country:'Germany'},
      { make: 'LAMBORGHINI', model: 'Aventador', price: 350000, country:'Italy' }
  ]
}
```

But the column header font family is not as I expected.

Do you have any Idea?

Comment: hi @AliMohammadi put this css in your main `style.css` file and let me know it is working or not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at below link.

[stackblitz-ag-grid-header-class](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ag-grid-angular-mclxbh)

I have made only one change, added `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` to apply css.

or you can put your css class to your main `style.css/style.scss` file

hope this would  help you, let me know if you still have an issue with it.

thanks

Comment: Amazing.I didn't find any documentation about it. Thanks a lot, bro.

Comment: I am unable to change the text alignment to right in the stackblitz example with the header style `my-header-class` to `text-align: right;` @kushal-shah is there a special requirement for aligning text? For now I am using `headerClass: 'ag-left-aligned-header'` but it may just be that ag-grid is using a default style if it gets something it does not recognize. (For reference I'm using `type: 'numericColumn'` but I want the header labels left aligned instead of right aligned like the cells.